# Symfony FOSRestBundle enableMaxDepthChecks default to true

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

Is it possible to set the default value for `enableMaxDepthChecks` to `true`?

Currently I have to add the following annotation to every route:

`@View(serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks=true)`

Is there a way to set this in the config or elsewhere to be the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this into your **config.yml**

```
jms_serializer:
    default_context:
        serialization:
            enable_max_depth_checks: true
```

BUT! After making these changes, the parameter `serializerEnableMaxDepthChecks` becomes non-working, so you can't set it to `false` , and I don't know why...